# Course allocation with array formula in Google spreadsheet using constraints

Tags: google-sheets

I try to assign students to courses based on the student's preference for each course and course capacity. Students are ranked based previous performance. In the current implementation, the data is obtained via Google Forms and other data sources. The aim is to use arrayformula() everywhere so that no manual processing would be required.

A very simplified sample data sheet without any formulas or external connections can be found here:
[sample data](https://docs.google.com/a/glion.ch/spreadsheets/d/1Q18goIe9vLMhjjmfnjqXHkjboVTQLQStmxfKQwhI2tw/edit?usp=sharing)

Top students are at the top and their choice is processed first.
A possible desired output (calculated manually) is also shown.

I can, with array formulas easily identify the first choices and calculate the accumulated sum for each course, but where I'm struggling with is applying the constraint once a class has reached it's limit: my formulas start having circular reference errors or out of bounds errors (when using offset's).

I would appreciate some guidance from the community.

Comment: The sample data now have the custom function from the [answer by Normal Human](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/81206/88163). The sample files should be kept unchanged or the data should be added to the body of the question so others could review the question as was before applying the answer suggestions .  The OP could add a link to another file with your attempt to apply the suggestions from one or several answers as result of the refinement of the question. By the way I have a similar question but is a bit complex.

Comment: Good point Normal human... I have restored the sample file to it's original state when the question was asked. and a new solution file an be found here: [link](https://docs.google.com/a/glion.ch/spreadsheets/d/1BIwUevPVIAuNdxWW3LSFvS3tEWEssB4NiGFDvYp_hrc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to do this with built-in spreadsheet functions is sure to be frustrating. But the problem is easily solved with a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) that [returns an array](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization):

```
=allocate(B3:G32, B36:G36)
```

The first argument is the list of preferences, the second is the list of class sizes. The output is a rectangular array with `1` marking enrollment. The function does not give you the actual enrollment in classes, which you can easily find with `SUM`.

Here is the function I wrote: it should be pasted into Script Editor, Tools > Script Editor...

```
function allocate(prefs, limits) {
  var remaining = limits[0], output = [];
  for (var i=0; i<prefs.length; i++) {
    output.push([]);
    for (var j=1; j<=prefs[i].length; j++) {
      var k = prefs[i].indexOf(j);
      if (k != -1 && remaining[k] > 0) {
        output[i][k] = 1; 
        remaining[k]--;
        break;
      }
    }
  }   
  return output;
}
```

Output for your example agrees with yours:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 1 |   |   |
|   |   |   | 1 |   |   |
|   |   |   | 1 |   |   |
|   | 1 |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   | 1 |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   | 1 |
|   |   |   |   |   | 1 |
| 1 |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   | 1 |   |   |
| 1 |   |   |   |   |   |
| 1 |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   | 1 |   |
| 1 |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   | 1 |
| 1 |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   | 1 |
|   |   |   |   |   | 1 |
|   |   |   |   | 1 |   |
|   |   |   |   | 1 |   |
|   |   |   |   | 1 |   |
|   |   |   |   | 1 |   |
|   |   | 1 |   |   |   |
|   | 1 |   |   |   |   |
|   |   | 1 |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   | 1 |   |
|   | 1 |   |   |   |   |
|   | 1 |   |   |   |   |
|   |   | 1 |   |   |   |
|   |   | 1 |   |   |   |
|   |   | 1 |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for the script solution, Normal Human. It was going to be my fallback solution if I did not find appropriate spreadsheet formulas. -- Peter

Comment: I can imagine doing what you want purely with built-in functions, but it would require using auxiliary cells outside of the output range (computing the availability of classes), then filtering preferences by availability, then picking the optimal... it's just a minefield of complex typo-prone formulas, most likely working _slower_ than a single call to a custom formula. And since the calculation involves 100+ cells depending on each other in complex ways, the whole chain of dependencies may never even resolve.

Comment: Indeed... I already now have several intermediate sheets with formula's, imports, queries, vlookups (because queries have no real join capability)-- peter

Comment: The script apparently works only on data that is static, not on dynamic data (pulled in from the form data using import range, array formula etc...). On my real data.. it hangs with "Loading..." forever.

Comment: @GenericITAccount appear that you have two issues 1) the referenced range size change over time 2) Google Apps Script processing limitations. Add more details to your question. A sample data file with the real layout will make your question more specific and the answerers could consider those details.

Comment: @Rubén:  I'll set up a demo later. I can't share the current dataset which contains lots of student and faculty details.

Comment: I implemented the script provided by Normal Human on the same data sheet so others can copy the sheet if they want to play with it.

Comment: @GenericITAccount in the meantime, in my copy I moved the summary cells from the bottom to the top. The following formula should solve problem 1 `=AllocateCourse(filter(B8:G,Len(B8:B)),B3:G3)`.

Comment: @Rubén Yes, indeed, my real data sheet does not have reference or summary data under the collected data as that can grow with several hundred entries: I have reference and summary data in different sheets- Peter

Comment: @GenericITAccount If your data is very large, consider time-based script that processes it every hour (instead of real time). Same logic, except the inputs are obtained via `getValues` method from some range, and output is placed via `setValues`. The details of ranges would depend on how the data is stored.  A function in Google Apps Script  can be executed every hour automatically by adding a trigger via the script editor.

Comment: @NormalHuman:  the script has an error as can be seen from the sheet [link](https://docs.google.com/a/glion.ch/spreadsheets/d/1e4vWpeOaVyR2sc_8FlkP6h5NJ-OwVemhNL-NFBEQ1lM/edit?usp=sharing) : when only choice 6 has space left, that choice is never selected...

Comment: @GenericITAccount I don't have permission to view that spreadsheet.

Comment: @ Normal Human - I'm very sorry for the sharing issue - I updated the sharing permission for the sheet that shows the condition under which no course is assigned : [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e4vWpeOaVyR2sc_8FlkP6h5NJ-OwVemhNL-NFBEQ1lM/edit?usp=sharing) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e4vWpeOaVyR2sc_8FlkP6h5NJ-OwVemhNL-NFBEQ1lM/edit?usp=sharing - The error in in L31 (in yellow): no course is assigned by the script

Comment: @GenericITAccount Indeed, the loop over j was iterating over 0...5 instead of 1...6.  You know... https://xkcd.com/163/  fixed now.